# Iframe designmode in Firefox problem

Tags: javascript

This works in IE, but in firefox it's very strange:

If open it normally if firefox, the designmode doesn't work but if i put a breakpoint on

> this.editor.contentWindow.document.designMode
>   = "On";

line, and then release it (after it breaks on it), the designmode works!

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">



TheEditor = function() {  
    this.editor = null;
    this.mainDiv=document.getElementById("mainDiv"); 
}

TheEditor.prototype = {

      InitializeEditor: function() {


        this.editor=document.createElement('iframe');
        this.editor.frameBorder=1;
        this.editor.width = "500px";
        this.editor.height="250px";       

        this.mainDiv.appendChild(this.editor);

        this.editor.contentWindow.document.designMode = "On";       
    }     


}
            window.onload = function(){
                obj = new TheEditor;
                obj. InitializeEditor();
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
       <div id="mainDiv">
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't full understand why, but opening (optionally writing content) and closing the document solves the issue (at least in FF5 on OSX):

```
this.editor.contentWindow.document.open();
// optionally write content here
this.editor.contentWindow.document.close();
this.editor.contentWindow.document.designMode = "on";
```

The other idea I had was to set a timeout around the `designMode = "on"` statement (I remember having to do this in the past for FF), but it did not work.

I think it has something to do with FF loading "something" in the IFRAME and it not being ready to turn designMode on.

I guess you could also use the `contentEditable="true"` attribute on the DIV instead.

Anyway, I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because the contentDocument not already created, I think you can also setup the iframe's onload event and set the design mode in this event, because this event is called when the page is loaded so the contentDocument exist !