# Iframe Design Mode in firefox not working

Tags: javascript, iframe

> I tried all works fine in all browser(including IE) but not in firefox

```
$("#"+selector).attr("contentEditable", "true");//worked but now not

    //document.getElementById(selector).setAttribute('contentEditable',true);

    //frames[selector].document.designMode = 'On';


    //document.getElementById(selector).contentDocument.designMode = "on";

    //frames[selector].document.body.setAttribute("contentEditable","true");
    //document.getElementById(selector).contentDocument.designMode = "on";//worked
    $('#'+selector).contents().prop('designMode','on');
    //$(this).contentDocument.designMode = "on";
```

Comment: any error in console?

Comment: no error. That's main problem :(

Comment: can you see that ?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2974375/iframe-designmode-in-firefox-problem